# Запятые при использовании оборота "перед тем, как"

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли в приведенном предложении запятая перед словом "желательно" и почему. 
"Перед тем, как идти на милонгу или другой тематический танцевальный вечер, желательно все же освоить базовые шаги".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запятая в сложных союзах ПЕРЕД ТЕМ КАК, ПОСЛЕ ТОГО КАК, ДЛЯ ТОГО ЧТОБЫ  и т. д. не ставится, если они находятся в начале предложения; если они в середине, тогда зяпятая нужна.
Так что нужно еще исправить ошибку в начале предложения.
А в том месте, о котором Вы спрашиваете, запятая нужна, потому что разделяет простые предложения в составе сложного.

Answer (score 0):

Да, тут запятая нужна - конец простого предложения с составе сложноподчиненного. Говоря проще, логически закрывается оборот "как идти... и т.д."